# Jquery Jslider shows wrong value on the hidden input field

Tags: jquery, jslider

I am trying to add a Jslider of price in my website.

here is the slider UI code in html

```
<div class="layout-slider">
<input id="Slider-price" type="slider" name="price" value="5;10" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

and the javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Slider-price').slider({from: '5',   to: '10', step: 1, dimension: '&nbsp;$' });
</script>
```

The original code is works well. Whicj is as same as the above code. But when I include it to my website, the `input` `value` goes wrong.

Fro example, if I give `value="5;10"` in my code, after running, it changes to `value="55;55"` and the value in javascript have no changes at all. Because of this, it didn't work and the slider pointer located at the end of the slider and cant slide it. What is wrong with this? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the to/from values are surrounded by single quotes and therefore being interpreted as strings  instead of integers.

```
'5' + '5' = '55'; // string concatenation
 5 + 5 = 10; // numeric addition
```

Remove the quotes on the to/from values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#Slider-price').slider({
    from: 5,
    to: 10,
    step: 1,
    dimension: '&nbsp;$'
  });
</script>
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/y2mPJ/